# Remove spaces at the end of class attribute

Tags: javascript, regex, html-parsing

I want to remove the spaces at the end of the `class` attribute in this string:

```
<div class="test  wrapper   " id="test"> " sample text " </div>
```

If I use

```
text = text.replace(/\s+"/g, '"');
```

then the space after `sample text` also will be removed and I want to keep that space.

Do you have any idea how can I do this?

Comment: Generally speaking, you should do this with regex. You can replace `replace(/\s+">/g, '">');` in this specific case.

Comment: @ndn class may not be last attribute then do you have any idea how can I do this?

Comment: `replace(/\s+"([^>]*)>/g, '"$1>');`, but again, use html parser.

Answer (score 2):

### Make your regex more specific

By adding `class="` to your regular expression, you can narrow the scope of the replacement. Then using a capturing group `()` and the `$n` replacement pattern, you can save just the list of class names excluding any spaces:

```js
var text = '<div class="test  wrapper   " id="test"> " sample test " </div>';
text = text.replace(/class="\s*(.+?)\s*"/g, 'class="$1"');
alert(text);
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want result which looks like
"sample test"
then use this code
with **js**:

> var str = " sample test   ";
>  var newStr = str.trim();
>  //
>   "sample test"

and with **js and regular expression**:
use this code:

> var str = " sample test   ";
>  var newStr =
>   str.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g,'');
>  // "sample test"